# mdiparent form inside mdiparent form

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

how to make mdiparent form inside mdiparent form in vb.et?

what i need is to make form two side one for buttoms and the left side if for forms,but i need this forms is tile windows.
i need any solution from this two :

1- i added allready mdiform inside it my forms and i make it tile windows,now i need to open this mdiparent form as mdichild form inside another mdiparent form.

or

2-i added all my mdichild forms inside splitecontainer inside mdiparent form,now the code for tilewindows not worked.how to make it worked?

```
 Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
 Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical)
```

Comment: You don't need an MDI form inside an MDI form,  It's just as well, because you can't do that anyway. Just add a `Panel` to your parent form and set its `Dock` property to `Left`.  You now have a docked `Panel` on the left where you can put your `Buttons` and the rest of the form area is the `MdiClient` for child forms.

Comment: thank you very much,add deleted the splitecontainer and i added panel and i maked it dock to left and i run my code mit worked but i lost the option from splitecontainer to move the splitecontainer.panel if i stay at the edge and click mouse and move with mouse,any solution for this , jmcilhinney

Comment: That's just drag and drop.  There's plenty of information about that around.

Comment: thank you for your replay,i solved it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you very much.
after discussion with jmcilhinney,i will put the final solution.

1- i used panel dock to left

2- i used splitter dock to left

so now i have options to resize the panel and to tile windows for my child forms easy, with this code:

```
Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileHorizontal)
Me.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.TileVertical)
```